# cakephp 3.2.7 pagination - page option ignored

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I'm using CakePHP 3.2.7. In my controller, I'm paginating a table as follows:

```
class CollectionsController extends AppController
{
public function index()
{
    $page_number = 1;
    $page_size = 10;

    if($this->request->query('page') !== null){
        if(array_key_exists('number', $this->request->query('page'))){
            $page_number = $this->request->query['page']['number'];
        }
        if(array_key_exists('size', $this->request->query('page'))){
            $page_size = $this->request->query['page']['size'];
        }
    }

    $this->paginate = [
        'limit' => $page_size,
        'page' => $page_number,
        //'order' => ['Collections.id' => 'desc']
    ];

    $collections = $this->paginate($this->Collections->find('all'));

    $this->set(compact('collections'));
    $this->set('_serialize', true);
}
}
```

The paginate options `limit` and `order` do work. However, the `page` and `offset` (not shown) options seem to be ignored. When printing the contents of `$this->request->params['paging']` (when requesting page 2 with size/limit of 2 of a table with 3 rows, query like `http://localhost:8765/api/collections?page[number]=2&page[size]=2`), I get:

```
"finder": "all",
"page": 1,
"current": 2,
"count": 3,
"perPage": 2,
"prevPage": false,
"nextPage": true,
"pageCount": 2,
"sort": null,
"direction": false,
"limit": null,
"sortDefault": false,
"directionDefault": false
```

The `perPage` option has the value of 2 (which I expect) BUT `page` has a value of 1 (when it should be 2). Why is the `page` option being ignored while other pagination options are working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that this had to do with the way I was structuring my url which was conflicting with the default behavior of pagination in CakePHP.

CakePHP automatically processes the `page` query string. While setting `'page' => $page_number,` for paginate options is valid and works, if there is a  `page` query string, it has priority over the paginate option.

In my case, I was following the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/examples/#pagination) example for the pagination url structure. This looks like `?page[number]=3&page[size]=1`. Since the query string `page` was present, it was overriding the paginate option I was setting. However, the value of `page` in this case was an associative array and not a number as the Paginator component expects. Therefore, the component uses its default value of 1.

This could be resolved by:

1. Using the default query string as intended (e.g. `?page=2&size=2`) (as mentioned by @Jsonras).
2. Using a different query string that doesn't conflict with `page` (e.g. `?paging[number]=3&paging[size]=1`) and setting the `page` option as in the question.
3. Keeping the same structure (`?page[number]=3&page[size]=1`) and overwriting the value of `page` query string after parsing the values. In this case, this code in the question,

   $this->paginate = [
               'limit' => $page_size,
               'page' => $page_number,
    ];

would change to:

```
$this->request->query['page'] = $page_number;
$this->paginate = [
        'limit' => $page_size,
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not page option for `$this->paginate` This is automatically done for you. All you have to do is pass page number.

See this: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html

Cake can also generate the pagination links for you. See here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html

If you're trying to build an API, this is the best way to do it using the CURD Plugin: http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-build-a-cakephp-3-rest-api-in-minutes/

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am trying to pass a page number as you mentioned. (please refer to this line in the question: `'page' => $page_number,`) . The issue is that regardless of what page number I'm setting, it always defaults to 1.

Comment: Right because you're not passing it correctly.  You don't need this code `page' => $page_number` that is what is taken care of for you automatically. First, remove `page' => $page_number` then go to your browser and `http://localhost:8765/api/collections?page=2&size=2` Also you need to fix this: `$page_size = $this->request->query['page']['size'];` to: `$page_size = $this->request->query['size'];` for the above url to work.